# arptables-nft persistence

Tags: debian, arp, netfilter, iptables-persistent

**Introduction**

This is on Debian Buster with kernel `4.19.0-6`

I've installed `iptables-persistent` and `netfilter-persistent` versions `1.0.11`

and added a basic rule to `arptables-nft` to block all LAN addresses but the default gateway like so:

```
# arptables-nft -A INPUT -s ! 10.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

saving the rules into a file can be done like so

```
$ sudo arptables-nft-save >> ~/Desktop/arptable-rules.save
$ less ~/Desktop/arptable-rules.save
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -s 10.0.0.1 --h-length 6 --h-type 1 -j DROP
```

And the rules can be restored like so

```
$ sudo arptables-nft -F
$ sudo arptables-nft-restore < ~/Desktop/arptable-rules.save
$ sudo arptables-nft -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
! -s 10.0.0.1 --h-length 6 --h-type 1 -j DROP

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
```

But for some reason, it does not persist past a reboot. I thought that arptables-nft would be part of the netfilter arp table, but it isn't. Aside from making a startup script (e.g. [Making scripts run at boot time with Debian](https://debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian)) which runs `arptables-nft-restore` and perhaps a shutdown script which runs `arptables-nft-save`, I am not sure how to make the `arptable-nft` table rules persistent past a reboot.

**Question**

Is there some way to have the rules automagically save like they do with `nft` or `iptables-persistent` and how they handle their tables? Or would writing a startup / shutdown script be less trouble?